# How can I use PUT for Creation

Tags: java, api, automated-tests, postman

I need to use PUT to create a new resource

```
{{url}}/resource/{id}
```

But when I put an id that doesn't exist, I have a message Error

```
"Can't find resource with id 20"
```

And when I put an existing id, it just updates it.

Code in postman with json :

```
{
    "id":"24",
    "Title":"new_data"  
}
```

Comment: Also one generally uses POST to create: PUT is for update. Check [this](https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/).

Comment: Thank you for your response

Lutz Horm, I see what you mean but i don't have the source code, i'll search more information about that.

Sterconium  Yes I know but I was asked to test Put for creation